# How to get the perfect calculation using the round() and number_format() in PHP

Tags: php, calculation

I have two calculations and whose answer should be something like this.

Miles per Gallon: 5.22
Litter per Kilometre: 45.09

But i am getting answer like this   MPG(5.31817920134) and LPK(44.2283704264).
Here is my code. Can anyone help fix this?

```
$fuelTotal = 74 + 91.5 + 128;  
$odometerTotal = 161.406 + 201.187 + 289.407;  
$fuelMPG = number_format(($odometerTotal * 0.621371) / (round($fuelTotal) / 3.78541), 2, '.', '');  
$fuelLPK = number_format((round($fuelTotal) / $odometerTotal) * 100, 2, '.', '');
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce https://3v4l.org/rFYXC, looks fine to me? `number_format()` does its job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here. I have tested your code as well, it gives round off by 2 only. Answer comes as expected.

The following code is for rounding off at 2 decimal numbers.

```
<?php
$fuelTotal = 74 + 91.5 + 128;  
$odometerTotal = 161.406 + 201.187 + 289.407;  
$fuelMPG = number_format(($odometerTotal * 0.621371) / (round($fuelTotal) / 3.78541), 2, '.', '');  
$fuelLPK = number_format((round($fuelTotal) / $odometerTotal) * 100, 2, '.', '');


echo round($fuelLPK, 2); //Will Round off LPK to 2 decimal points.
echo round($fuelMPG , 2); //Will Round off MPG to 2 decimal points.
?>
```

Comment: What about the *Miles per Gallon* and *Litter per Kilometre*?

Comment: The code OP provided works just fine. however they can just substitute `$fuelTotal` with `$fuelMPG` or `$fuelLPK` and it should work.